# React-Native: this.something.map inside a for loop to access data from data array in .json file..could any one suggest an example sample code?

Tags: javascript, android, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm net to RN, and I wanted to try out mapping data from a data array in .json file inside a for loop if possible or any looping but it should map from the data array.

Could anyone suggest a code example i could try out? as I tried the following, which i could'nt add a .map variable to it.

***JSON DATA ARRAY (.json)***

```
[
 {
"name": {
  "first": "abc",
  "last": "xyz"
},
"position": "Software Developper",

"photo": "http://www.lilavatihospital.com/Admin/Doctors/doctor.jpg"
 },
  {
"name": {
  "first": "sdf",
  "last": "xyz"
},
"photo": "http://www.lilavatihospital.com/Admin/Doctors/doctor.jpg"
 },
 {
"name": {
  "first": "abby",
  "last": "xyz"
},
"photo": "http://www.lilavatihospital.com/Admin/Doctors/doctor.jpg"
 }
]
```

***JS file***

```
renderItem() { 
const elements = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  elements.push(
    <Text>
      {users[i].name.first}
    </Text>,
  );
}
return elements;
  }
  render() {
return (
  <View>
    {this.renderItem()}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: so you want to get data from json with array.map() ?

Comment: Yes maybe if it could iterate a value such as array.map() but for example users.name.first inside some looping like for loop or so?result stored into some variable?

Comment: i will suggest use dataArray and renderItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you can try like this :

```
renderItem() { 
    const elements = [];
    const array = users.map(function(x,i){
        elements.push(x.name.first)
        return (
            <Text key={i}>{x.name.first}</Text>
        );
    })
    console.log(elements);
    return array;
}
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderItem()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

So value of variable `elements` is `['abc','sdf','abby']`.
I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: yes thank you @srsugara, it is working with this code :)

Comment: but I just noticed, I get an warning saying that each child in an array or iterator should have a unique key property?

Comment: i have updated the answer, you just add `key` to component that return from array.map().

Comment: Yeah I did try it out, but do i need to add any key or something to the .json file as I am still getting the previous warning.

Comment: you can use index from array.map() as key, like `users.map(function(x,i){...}` and `key={i}` and i have tried on my project and the warning has been lost